# Determine the range of $p$ respectively when the series converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Determine the range of $p$ respectively, when $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\dfrac{\sin n}{n^p + \sin n} + \dfrac{\cos ^2 n}{n^{2p}} \right)$$ converges or diverges.

That is, when does the series converge? And when does it diverge?

I have no idea about the problem. It seems so hard to determine the range of $p$, since the denominator of the items is complicated. Can anyone help?

Comment: I would guess that $p > 1$ will converge. It might help to begin checking smaller values of $p$ after that.

Comment: This is likely to get closed for  lack of evidence of effort.  Try showing absolute convergence by bounding with $p > 1$.  I'll give you a hint for $p < 1$ below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split partial sums. For $0 < p < 1$, work with

$$\frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{2p}}= \frac{1}{2n^{2p}}+ \frac{\cos 2n}{2n^{2p}},$$
$$\frac{\sin n}{n^p + \sin n} = 1 - \frac{1}{1+ \frac{\sin n}{n^p}} = \frac{\sin n}{n^p} - \frac{\sin ^2n}{n^{2p}} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-3p})$$

Comment: Could you expand more details?

Comment: For example $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos^2 n}{n^{2p}}= \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{2n^{2p}}+ \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\cos 2n}{2n^{2p}}$.  First sum converges if $2p>1$ and diverges otherwise.  Second sum converges if $2p > 0$ by the Dirichlet test etc.